# How declare a variable in trigger, because MySQL said unknown column 'id_productos' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, database

I am newbie, I am creating a trigger, when insert in detail_providers, update the price and existence fields in table products, where the id that has detail_providers, is the same as product_product, but MySQL says that the column_products of detail_providers is unknown , Someone who can help me?

This is the trigger:

```
create trigger DetalleProductos 
after insert on detalle_proveedores for each row
UPDATE productos set precio_producto = new.costo_detalle_proveedor * 1.3,
existencia_producto= new.existencias_detalle_proveedores 
where id_productos=id_producto;


    Error.
    ERROR 1054: 1054: Unknown column 'id_productos' in 'where clause'
    SQL Statement:
    INSERT INTO `punto_de_venta`.`detalle_proveedores`
    (`id_detalle_proveedores`, `id_proveedor`, 
     `existencias_detalle_proveedores`, `costo_detalle_proveedor`, 
     `fecha_detalle_proveedor`, `id_productos`, `nombre_producto`) VALUES 
    ('21', '15', '20', '170', '2017-09-09', '31', 'Cama')
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of `detalle_proveedores` and `productos` tables?.

Comment: Guessing your WHERE needs to be `WHERE NEW.id_productos = id_producto` _.... honestly, you're lucky the tables have different field names, otherwise that would've updated the entire `productos` table._

Comment: It worked, thank you very much, seriously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the `NEW` database in your `where` clause:

```
where NEW.id_productos = id_producto
```

See this example from [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

```
CREATE TABLE test1(a1 INT);
CREATE TABLE test2(a2 INT);
CREATE TABLE test3(a3 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE test4(
  a4 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  b4 INT DEFAULT 0
);

delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test2 SET a2 = NEW.a1;
    DELETE FROM test3 WHERE a3 = NEW.a1;
    UPDATE test4 SET b4 = b4 + 1 WHERE a4 = NEW.a1;
  END;
|

delimiter ;

INSERT INTO test3 (a3) VALUES
  (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL),
  (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL);

INSERT INTO test4 (a4) VALUES
  (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0);
```